# Generate Signed APK wizard dialogue not starting on Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android

I am trying to publish an app on Android Studio 3.2 Canary 13. Nothing seems to happen when I click ***Build*** > ***Generate Signed APK*** on the studio. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android Studio 3.2 Canary n**

An early version of a program or application that contains most of the major features, but is not yet complete. So for this issue, You should use **STABLE** version. A new ***Android Studio 3.1.2*** is available in the stable channel.

**Try this( Quick Solutions )**

- Restart Android Studio. **File->Invalid Caches/Restart**